# How to determine the intersection of two graphs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

For example, I have the following two variables:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 3, 1];
b = [0, 4, 2, 4, 6];
```

If I draw their diagram, it will be as follows:

```
plot(a)
hold on
plot(b)
```

[image: plot of a and b]

I want to specify the intersection of the two graphs. That is, if the red graph goes above the blue graph, it shows a solid red dot. And if the red graph goes down the blue graph, the red dot shows emptiness. (Like the photo below)

[image: desired plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gives the desired result.

[image: plot]

This is mainly done in three steps

1. Get the points where a crossing happens, identified by `diff(a>b)` being non-zero, i.e. a change in which of the two is larger.
2. Work out the straight line equations for the relevant line segments where a crossing occurs
3. Plot either a filled or hollow marker at these points

Step 2 is arguably the trickiest, I've been lazy and used `polyfit` to fit a straight line between the two surrounding points at each marker location, which is likely not very performant but it works without too much thinking!

```
% Input
a = [1, 3, 5, 3, 1];
b = [0, 4, 2, 4, 6];

% Helper arrays to detect rise/fall in crossings
x = 1:numel(a);
idx = [0, diff(a > b)];
incIdx = idx == 1;
decIdx = idx == -1;

% Plot
figure(10); clf; hold on
plot(x,a);
plot(x,b);
for ii = 1:numel(idx)
    if decIdx(ii) || incIdx
        % Rise or fall, get the crossing point
        [xc,yc] = crossing( x(ii-1:ii), a(ii-1:ii), b(ii-1:ii) );
        % Plot filled or hollow marker as desired
        if incIdx(ii)
            plot( xc, yc, 'or', 'markersize', 10 );
        elseif decIdx(ii)
            plot( xc, yc, 'or', 'markersize', 10, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r' );
        end
    end
end


function [xc,yc] = crossing(x,y1,y2)
    % Find intersection of lines with two shared x axis value pair and 
    % given pairs of y values
    p1 = polyfit(x,y1,1);
    p2 = polyfit(x,y2,1);    
    xc = (p2(2)-p1(2))/(p1(1)-p2(1));
    yc = p1(1)*xc + p1(2);
end
```